# Access SQL database in postgres for routing

Tags: postgresql, sql-server

i am trying to access sql database in pgadminIII. Using postgres_fdw I am trying to connect. But I am struck in the middle..Following are the steps I followed

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgres_fdw;

CREATE SERVER ws253 FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgres_fdw OPTIONS (host '192.168.0.253', dbname 'allahabad', port '1433');

CREATE USER MAPPING FOR postgres SERVER ws253 OPTIONS (user 'sa', password 'track');

CREATE FOREIGN TABLE routing
(
 gid serial NOT NULL,
 name character varying(255),
 district character varying(255),
 state character varying(255),
 the_geom geometry,
 name_hindi character varying,
 name_hindi_display character varying(255)
)
SERVER ws253;
```

What is the next step I have to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think now you are able to connect to the remote server with [pgadminIII](http://www.pgadmin.org/docs/dev/connect.html) or with [psql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150738/cannot-connect-to-postgres-from-remote-host).
Be careful to have the grants to access the server.

Comment: is there any routing algorithm for mssql 2012 @MicklnTheSky?

Comment: @Vikram - Sorry, but I don't understand your question. What do you want to do actually? Simply connect to server or something else? In the first case I think to have done the answer, other  you should perhaps specify your question or, better, open another post.